# mongodb datasource configuration

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am getting this error, don't have an idea how to clear this issue. My data source refers to my local machine.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Data source is an invalid type.  It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource. 
>     Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Data source is an invalid type.  It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource.

Source Error:

```
var connectionstring = "mongodb://abc:efg@xx.xxx.xx.xxx:27017";
MongoClient client = new MongoClient(connectionstring);                    
var mongoDatabase = client.GetDatabase("test");
var collection = mongoDatabase.GetCollection<era>("ERa");                     
GridView1.DataSource = collection;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: If you want to get all objects in the collection try something like this: `GridView1.DataSource = collection.Find(_ => true).ToList();`

Comment: It throws an error - Server Error in '/' Application. A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting......... Source Error: var list = collection.Find(_ => true).ToList(); GridView1.DataSource = list; GridView1.DataBind(); –

Comment: Can you verify that the connection to your database works?

Comment: u r right... it is not connected properly.. but i dont know where i have made mistake. Also, my data source file path is in my d drive.. but while running it shows like source="admin". is that fine?

Comment: What part shows 'source="admin" '? Is your mongo database running? Is the connection string the right one? Did the connection to the database succeed ever before?

Comment: yes i have given the right connection string and also db works fine, no problem in that. also @mongoclient client = new mongoclient(connectionstring); while executing this line.. it shows cluster->description-> state as "disconnected"